# Error al conectar Java a SQL Server con JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Buenas, tengo el siguiente código

```
public class main {


    private static Connection cn;

    public static Connection getConexion() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Persona");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            cn = null;
        }

        return cn;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //menuPrincipal mp = new menuPrincipal();
        //mp.setVisible(true);

        Connection prueba = main.getConexion();

        if (prueba != null) {
            System.out.println("Conexion realizada con exito...");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error en la conexion...");
        }
    }
}
```

El cual me retorna "Error en la conexion". He logrado realizar la misma mediante el panel "Services" como pueden ver a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero mi método no me retorna lo que busco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo te falta el usuario y la contraseña, checa este blog https://elbauldelprogramador.com/conectar-base-de-datos-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Se recomienda tener una clase dedicada a la Conexión, no hacerlo dentro de `Main`. Así, cada vez que necesites la conexión creas una instancia de la misma. En la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java)  tienes ejemplos explicados sobre cómo proceder. [En este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample)  puedes ver otro ejemplo oficial.

Comment: Lucas te recomiendo en exceso que no trabajes con el driver de SQLServer 2015 es un verdadero dolor de cabeza, utiliza jtds es problemático pero no tanto como SQLServer 

La url solo cambia en jdbc:jtds:sqlserver... y el driver sería  net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.3.1/

Comment: Gracias Ajeno! Pero por desgracia en la universidad nos hacen trabajar de esta forma.

Comment: Dos cosas: desde Java 7, no necesitas usar `Class.forName(...)`, y puedes ahorrarte mucho usando `DriverManager.getConnection(<url que ya tienes>, <usuario>, <contraseña>);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta agregar un properties en el que se agreguen el usuario y la contraseña de acceso

```
Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
connectionProps.put("user", "userName");
connectionProps.put("password", "password");
DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Persona, connectionProps);
```

Comment: Pude solucionarlo con un poco de ayuda de todos. Cambie esta linea y me quedo asi: 
cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Persona;user=mi_usuario;password=mi_contraseña");

Muchas gracias!